# Add header to all requests in AngularJS application created by Yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just built my very first `AngularJS` application using `Yeoman`. I've done it like so:

```
$ yo angular frontend
```

As a result, I've got a bunch of standard folders and files like:

```
- app
    - images
    - scripts
        app.js
    - styles
    - views
    index.html
    ...
- bower_components
- node_modules
- test
```

It seems like I have to change app.js file in order to add a header to all requests. But I'm terribly new to AngularJs and I do not know what should I exactly do. Now, app.js looks like:

```
angular
    .module('frontend', [
        ...
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when(...)
    });
```

I guess, I need to set `$httpProvider`, but how can I do that?

Comment: Start by readung the [$httpProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `interceptor` for this. Here is the recommended way from the AngularJS docs:

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

All you need to do is implement the `'request'` method, as all methods are optional. The config object provided is an angular `$http` config object, and it contains a `headers` property. You should be able to add your header easily enough to this:

```
config.headers.myHeader = myValue;
return config;
```

You can grab the `$httpProvider` in your config blog simply by adding it to the arguments list:

```
angular
    .module('frontend', [
        ...
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $provide){
        $routeProvider
            .when(...)

        // register the interceptor as a service
        $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
          return {
            // optional method
            'request': function(config) {
              config.headers.myHeader = myValue;
              return config;
            },
          };
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    });
```

Comment: Should I put this code in `app.js` file? And still what is the right way to set some arbitrary header for all request, if I use such an `interceptor`? I guess, I should edit `request` method?

Comment: Can also set defaults without needing an interceptor

Comment: @charlietfl. Would you be so kind, to give a code snippet, that I should add to my app.js file to set a header, using defaults? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the bottom code block with an example for how to implement the interceptor. However the original example was quite simple, if you don't understand there are many good AngularJS tutorials out there. We can guide you to the answer but we're not going to write your code out for you.

Comment: The only problem, that I see here is that this header is not submitted, when I request the root page. Rather strange.

Comment: The root page is not requested with Angular, it's a regular HTTP GET request made by the browser and you can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution to add headers in all request is

```
app.run(['$http', function ($http) {
   $http.defaults.headers.common['myHeader'] = 'myHeaderValue';
}]);
```